# readAsDataUrl function no output

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, capacitor

i am using ionic 5 & capacitor.
For some reason, the readAsDataURL isnt working and it isnt showing me an error message either.
the path & file name seem fine, they are :

filePath: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/1763816379-cropped.jpg

path : file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/

fileName: 1763816379-cropped.jpg

```
 showCroppedImage(ImagePath) {
    var filePath = ImagePath;
    let fileName = filePath.split("/").pop();
    let path = filePath.substring(0, filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    alert(filePath);
    alert(fileName);
    alert(path);
    alert("works till here");
    this.file
      .readAsDataURL(path, fileName)
      .then((base64) => {
        alert(base64);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        alert(err);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this?  I am experiencing the same issue. I get a 404 error, and with a little bit of debugging its due to " file:///storage/emulated/0/An" not being allowed access.  Just its the only way for crop to access the file, as the webPath doesn't work.  Base64 also doesn't work as it won't even crop.

Comment: I actually don't remember what i had done, give me a day or two, I'll figure it out and get back to you. Meanwhile, if you want,
here is the code i had used : [github](https://github.com/AaryaDevnani/ImageCropper/blob/master/src/app/home/home.page.ts)
okay, I think I figured it out, if possible, can please I see your code ?

Comment: @fromage9747 I added a solution below, check it out! Please let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.file.createFile(
    this.file.externalDataDirectory,
    "base64string.txt",
    true
  );
  this.file.readAsText(this.file.externalDataDirectory, "base64string.txt");
  this.blob = new Blob([this.base64string]);
  this.file
    .writeFile(
      this.file.externalDataDirectory,
      "base64string.txt",
      this.blob,
      { replace: true, append: false }
    )
    .then(() => {
      alert("File saved in internal storage/android/data/io.starter.ionic/");
});
}
```

Earlier, my file was getting saved in an internal directory which was not accessible by a user. So i used the externalDataDirectory function, which fixed my issue. It stores the file in an external directory which is accessible by the user.
The file is stored in "internal storage/android/data/#app_id#/"

Comment: Should've come back to this and put my own answer.  Shortly after adding a comment on the OP, I figured out a way to do what I wanted. I ended up using const base64 = await Filesystem.readFile({ path: ImagePath});

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sorting the problem for my application and I have included it below:

```
/** @desc crop the selected image */
async cropImage(fileUrl: any) {
    this.show_spinner = true;
    await this.ionLoader.showLoader('Cropping Image...');
    this.crop.crop(fileUrl, {
      quality: 75,
      targetHeight: 320,
      targetWidth: 240
    })
      .then(
        async (newImage) => {
          this.show_spinner = false;
          await this.ionLoader.hideLoader();
          this.showCroppedImage(newImage.split('?')[0]);
        },
        async (error: IonicResultMessageInterface) => {
          this.show_spinner = false;
          await this.ionLoader.hideLoader();
          console.error('Error cropping image', error);
          console.log(error);
          this.setUserProfileImage();
          this.toasterService.showToast(error.message, 'failure');
        }
      );
  }
  /** @desc show the image after it has been cropped */
  async showCroppedImage(ImagePath: string) {
    console.log(ImagePath);
    this.show_spinner = true;
    const copyPath = ImagePath;
    const splitPath = copyPath.split('/');
    const imageName = splitPath[splitPath.length - 1];
    const file_ext = imageName.substr(imageName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    try {
      const base64 = await Filesystem.readFile({ path: ImagePath});
      if (base64) {
        console.log(base64);
        this.userImageUrl = 'data:image/' + file_ext + ';base64,' + base64.data;
        this.show_spinner = false;
        await this.updateProfilePictureMethod();
      } else {
        this.show_spinner = false;
        console.log('Error in the showCroppedImage File method');
        console.log('Unexpected Error');
        this.setUserProfileImage();
        this.toasterService.showToast('Unexpected Error Occurred in the showCroppedImage File', 'failure');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.show_spinner = false;
      console.log('Error in the showCroppedImage File method');
      console.log('Unexpected Error');
      this.setUserProfileImage();
      this.toasterService.showToast(error.message, 'failure');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi fromage, Thanks for your answer, I am getting the error file does not exist in showCroppedImage, Can you please guide me a bit?